# Which LLVM 3-tuple targets have any non-Swift non-Objective-C language other than Xamarin-based languages been able to utilize Swift-only frameworks?

Tags: swift, frameworks, interop

- For example, **Kotlin** has the ability to utilize Objective-C frameworks when developing for MacOS or iOS/iPadOS/tvOS/watchOS.  Kotlin is a non-Apple language (i.e., not Swift and not Objective-C).  Kotlin is a non-Xamarin language.  But Kotlin currently has no ability to utilize Swift frameworks (e.g., SwiftUI, Combine).
- Historically **Python** also seems to have had experimental ability to invoke Objective-C frameworks. https://omz-software.com/pythonista/docs/ios/objc_util.html
- Historically **OCaml** has demonstrated this ability to interoperate with Objective-C frameworks (but not Swift-only frameworks).  http://psellos.com/ocaml/compile-to-iphone.html
- **Lua** has the ability to interoperate with Objective-C frameworks (but not Swift-only frameworks).  https://bounces.dev/en/documentation/lua-code/lua-native-bridge

But of all non-Apple languages, it seems that only **C#** via (non-Forms) Xamarin has been able to interoperate with Swift-only frameworks (e.g., SwiftUI).  It seems from the source that this feat has been achieved only by manually writing a binding (instead of by infrastructural introspection).  Due to being Xamarin (and thus C#-focused) this means that C#'s generational automatic garbage collection is utilized instead of Apple's ARC reference counting.  https://github.com/chkn/Xamarin.SwiftUI

If any non-Apple programming language has 1) interoperability with Swift-only frameworks (e.g., SwiftUI, Combine) and 2) has successful submissions to Apple AppStore for iOS or MacOS X, then which *3-tuple LLVM target* has been utilized successfully to submit that an app written in those languages to iOS/iPadOS AppStore or MacOS AppStore (Intel & Apple M1 ARM)?

Comment: Not sure where do you want to get with this. Assuming there are 3-tuple LLVM targets like you described, what is the goal you want to achieve? Also what exactly do you mean by "3-tuple LLVM target"?

Comment: LLVM Targets are represented as a machine-vendor-operatingSystem triple or 3-tuple, e.g., ppc-apple-darwin, arm-none-eabi, x86_64-apple-darwin16.1.0, but it has evolved beyond 3 fields to effectively be 4 fields with 3 hyphens <arch><sub>-<vendor>-<sys>-<abi> nowadays as in x86_64-w64-windows-gnu, so the “triple” effectively refers to the maximum number of hyphens instead of the maximum number of fields.  https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Triple.html  and  https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/e571ed  I seek the triple as evidence that someone went all the way to AppStore-submittable output.